# looking for tutorials or books explain in details AndroidCamera and SurfaceView?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I'm lookin for a good book or tutorial explains in detail how to deal with and handle  AndroidCamera and the SurfaceView interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Busy Coder's Guide to Advanced Android Development. There's a chapter dedicated to Camera and it's a good book. By Mark L Murphy published by CommonsWare. http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/